# Compute/parse list elements (links) in parallel

Tags: parsing, scala, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrent-programming

Can't understand what's the right way to compute elements of list in parallel, but block main thread while elements are not computed (in parallel). Use case: i have a list of URL links and  a simple parser for html page, i what to reduce the amount of time needed to grab info from the given pages by parsing each page in parallel and then return a simple list with some JSON data.

As i understand i have two options:

**Concurrent way with Futures**

I have a method with extract some JSON data in Future:

```
def extractData(link: String): Future[JValue] = // some implementation
```

and i just map it over a list of links, which type would be List[Future[JValue]]:

```
val res: List[Future[JValue]] = listOfLink.map(extractData)
```

If i call `sequence` (for example from Scalaz, or my own implementation) which traverse this list and convert it to `Future[List[JValue]]`, then links still gonna be processed sequentially, but a separate thread, which won't give me any efficiency, cause in result i need to get a `List[JValue]`.

**Try to compute with ParSeq**

In this option i have a function which just extracts data:

```
def extractData(link: String): JValue = // some implementation
```

but this time call `.par` on the collection:

```
val res: ParSeq[JValue] = listOfLinks.map(extractData)
```

But in this way i don't quite understand how to block main thread while the hole list won't be computed, without parsing each link sequentially

As for the Akka, i just can't use actors here, so only `Future` or `Par*`

Comment: When I look in the implementation of the map function in the class `ParIterableLike`there is written `...tasksupport.executeAndWaitResult...`. I don't understand all details but maybe that means that the thread will already be blocken by this implementation. Another aproach with the `Futures` would be `flatMap` instead of `map` to combine the single `Futures` to one `Future` that will be ready when all the "little" `Future`s are ready. I can't tell this for sure, because I am learning scala, too, with the same questions raising up. ;) Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The links *will* be processed in parallel when you map `extractData` over the collection. Consider a slightly simplified example:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def extractData(s: String) = future {
  printf("Starting: %s\n", s)
  val i = s.toInt
  printf("Done: %s\n", s)
  i
}

val xs = (0 to 5).map(_.toString).toList

val parsed = Future.sequence(xs map extractData)
```

Now you'll see something like the following, which makes it clear that these things aren't being processed sequentially:

```
Starting: 0
Done: 0
Starting: 2
Done: 2
Starting: 1
Starting: 4
Done: 1
Starting: 3
Starting: 5
Done: 5
Done: 4
Done: 3
```

Note that you can use `Future.traverse` to avoid creating the intermediate list of futures:

```
val parsed = Future.traverse(xs)(extractData)
```

In either case you can block with `Await`:

```
val res = Await.result(parsed, duration.Duration.Inf)
```

As a footnote: I don't know if you're planning to use [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) to perform the HTTP requests, but if not, it's worth a look. It also provides nicely integrated JSON parsing, and the documentation is full of useful examples of how to work with futures.